# Spring mvc, hibernate LazyInitializationException when converting entity to dto

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Why I am getting this error? This is the portion of my daoImpl Im calling

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Person> getAllPersons(){
        List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Person.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .list();
        return persons;
    }
```

Portion of my person model

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Contact> contacts;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_ROLE", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
```

In my service impl, I convert model to dto using `BeanUtils`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that in a time when you try to convert the entity to dto using `BeanUtils` the entity is already detached (e.g. outside persistence context/hibernate session). In your `Person` class you have a `Set<Contact>` of contacts which is loaded lazily - that is why it fails.

If `Contact` does not contain many relations you might change to `FetchType.EAGER` or you can convert entity while `Person` is still attached.

Answer (score 0):

In the BeanUtils, you need to initialize the objects via Hibernate as follows:

```
    MyProfile pf = null;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from MyProfile as term where term.profileId=:pId ");
        query.setString("pId", pid);
        pf = (MyProfile)query.uniqueResult();
        if(pf != null)
        {
            Hibernate.initialize(pf);
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        throw he;
    }
```

Using Hibenrate.initialize(pf) will initialize the objects contained inside MyProfile object.